# How to write a regex to differentiate between sentence end full stops and abbreviation full stops

Tags: java, regex

I have an .xlsx with cells containing text. I'm trying to write Java code that would output each cell to a separate .txt file, with each sentence being in a new line in the output file. The sentences are not in new lines in the .xlsx.

It would be easy to split the source strings along full stops, but the text also contains many abbreviations, which is why I tried using a regex that differentiates between sentence end full stops and abbreviation full stops. As it is now, it fails and the sentences are not split at all.
I also cannot use a library for sentence recognition, as no library that has sentence recognition exists for the language of the source text.

How to modify the regex to successfully differentiate between sentence and abbreviation full stops and split the text along sentence fullstops?

```
   String[] sentences = combinedText.split("(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=[A-ZĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪ])");
   StringBuilder cleanedText = new StringBuilder();
      for (String sentence : sentences) {
         String cleanedSentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s.ąčęėįšųūĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪ]", "").trim();
         if (!cleanedSentence.isEmpty()) {
             cleanedText.append(cleanedSentence).append("\n");
         }
      }
```

Comment: This may not even be possible via regex alone _but_ back in the day a period full stop was always followed by 2 spaces.  If you make this assumption, then it's easy to identify a full stop vs. an abbreviation.

Comment: What you want is impossible, Andrius. Here are two sentences to prove this: "I saw Notorious B.I.G. 5 times in concert." vs "I saw Notorious B.I.G. 5 days later I bought the CD." - Other than text analysis Artificial Intelligence options to attempt to disentangle these cases, you can't do it.  Post a whole heap of examples (maybe you can scan for dot, some space, capital letter?) and state how inaccurate the result can be (because if you need perfection, you're in trouble here), or go back to where you read these cells out and find a different solution there.

Comment: Java’s little secrets: [`BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/BreakIterator.html#getSentenceInstance())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible solely with RegEx, unless you know something about the data eg. "all abbreviations contain a capital letter".

See this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation

If the dataset is not so huge, I would suggest writing an expression to catch as many ambiguous cases as possible, which you can check manually. For example:

- Find all cases where the letter preceding the full stop character is a capital letter
- Find all cases where there are two full stops with less than, say, 6 characters between (a likely abbreviation)
- Find all cases where the first character after the full stop is lower case

If the dataset is large, you could consider using a more comprehensive tool such as [Natural Language Toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Toolkit) which provides sentence detection capabilities.